# How is the the lower-limit of the proton lifetime measured experimentally?

Tags: experimental-physics, standard-model

Wikipedia says :

Recent experiments at the Super-Kamiokande water Cherenkov radiation detector in Japan gave lower limits for proton half-life, at 90% confidence level, of 6.6×10^33 years via antimuon decay and 8.2×1033 years via positron decay. Newer, preliminary results estimate a half-life of no less than 1.29×10^34 years via positron decay.

So how is the lower limit of the proton lifetime measured in this experiment ?

Answer (score 3):

I think they just take a large amount of material and look for protons decaying in it. There are a lot of protons, so in order for none of them to decay the half-life must be absurdly long.

Comment: Exactly, if you look at 100 protons for 1 second, it's the same as looking at 1 proton for 100 seconds.

They look at a huge quantity of water, looking for a p->e+X or p->mu+X where the anti-electron or anti-muon will emit Cherenkov light.

The rate of such event helps to set a limit on proton lifetime.

Comment: The devil is in the details, of course. These detector show events due to other physics (cosmic rays, cosmic neutrinos, solar neutrinos, radiological contamination, in the case of Super-K there are beam neutrinos from T2K) quite regularly, so sorting out one from another is the hard part.